# Command Prompt - jar files

Tags: java, jar

This is how I currently compile my code:

```
jar cvf client.jar tileGen.class tileGen$GamePanel.class Player.class
```

Well let's say I have a folder called \line_tile| and i want to put in that jar file all of the png files... like this. \line_tile*.png maybe? So in the Jar file it would be my tileGen, tileGen$GamePnale, and player classes then a new folder called \line_tile\ and inside THAT ... I would have my tile images.... maybe you can help?

I don't know...

Comment: A note on nomenclature - that isn't how you *compile* your code, that's how you package your compiled classes into a JAR file.  You compile your code with `javac`, like the rest of us. :-)

Comment: Or `ejc` like the rest of the rest of us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

`jar cvf client.jar tileGen.class tileGen$GamePanel.class Player.class line_tile`

This will include everything in a "line_tile" directory in your jar.

It's easiest to build the jar if all the files you want are in the location on the drive where you want them. You want the line_tile directory right where you are building your jar.

Answer (score 1):

```
jar cvf client.jar tileGen.class tileGen$GamePanel.class Player.class line_tile/*.png
```